# Relation of Score function of a normal pdf and the z-score?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, likelihood, z-score

Suppose we have a density function $f \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then, the score function is defined to be:

$$
\frac{d}{d\mu}\log f\left(x;\mu,\sigma^2\right)
$$

The answer to this for the normal is:

$$
\frac{d}{d\mu}\log f\left(x;\mu,\sigma^2\right) = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}
$$

which looks uncannily like the z-score. Is there a deeper relation here? Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "deeper relation"?  The score functions give first-order differential equations for the densities, thereby defining the family of distributions.  Thus, different distributions will give rise to different score functions and *vice versa*.  Consequently, the meaning of your question seems to rest on how we are supposed to interpret "uncannily."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [set of tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_test) based on the score function. For a normal distribution, it gives the standard z-test. I think with parametric tests for normal distributions you always going to end up with the same test, it's fundamentally the only reasonable thing to do (without going non-parametric).